# How to prevent user zoom in a desktop web app?

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, safari, webkit, gesture

I am attempting to use HTML 5 technologies to create an application that runs in the Chrome browser on the desktop. One of my challenges is that there seems to be no way to do the equivalent of:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-height, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
```

on the desktop. I found an issue reported against chromium, but it appears to have been ignored.

To get a feel for the problem, visit maps.google.com in Chrome or Safari on a Mac, and do a pinch-zoom gesture. Instead of the map zooming in, as users would expect, the browser just creates a huge unusable mess.

Given that Google Maps and Chrome are developed by the same company, this is feeling like a fairly hopeless cause. But this seems like a pretty fundamental flaw in the whole "Web Application" concept. Creating a native experience is impossible if the browser won't even let you control something as basic as having your virtual viewport be the same size as your window.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Google Maps actually reacts perfectly well to zooming, and everything remains usable at the new zoom level. True, it does not zoom _the map_, but restricting the user zooming would be much worse from a usability perspective. Not everybody in the world is able to read your web application at the font size you have picked as perfect for _yourself_; many people have actual disabilities and _need_ to be able to zoom in.

Comment: Actually, pinch-zooming yields a horrible user experience in which the user is forced to pan using scroll bars, and pop-up information is off the screen. You are missing the point entirely, which is that I'm writing an application, not a web site. As an application developer, it's my job to think about resolution issues, and I will deal with them. This is *exactly* what the meta/viewport tag is for on mobile. Without that tag supported, writing applications hosted in a browser is next to impossible.

Comment: Oh, and as for users with disabilities: the operating system already handles this. There are text voice-overs, O/S level zoom and resolution controls, etc.

Comment: Your _only_ example of a web-app handles zooming flawlessly. I have yet to see what problems you _actually_ encounter with user zooming. And apparently you have never tried OS-level zooming.

Comment: When writing applications, we developers should endeavor to create user interfaces that act the way our users expect. A user would expect that pinch-zooming the map in google maps would zoom the map. The fact that it doesn't is a problem. The fact that it does something which breaks the user interface (by putting important information off-screen) is a bigger problem. At a minimum, developers should be able to disable this kind of zoom in web applications. Ideally, developers should be able to override the default pinch-zoom gesture to make it appropriate for the app.

Comment: Not sure if you are still interested in it, but you write you are implementing your application using "HTML5 technologies". Which are these? Are you using e.g. a `<canvas>` object?

Comment: WebGL, actually. Along with lots of CSS3. If you drill down into one of the 3D product models, and try pinch-zoom, you'll see the mess created by not being able to intercept these gestures. http://goo.gl/cXKjD

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same issues. I recently found this:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event){
    if(event.touches.length >=2) {
        event.stopPropagation(); 
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```

But if the users acts really fast it still works. This is really annoying in a kiosk setting where a user does a pinch zoom on accident and has no idea what happened so the kiosk is just broken. 
I'll keep posting if I find a solution

Comment: While some desktop browsers do deliver touch events like that when you use them in Windows 8 on touch screen notebooks, most do not, and none do when you use trackpads to pinch. Although, I guess on a Kiosk, you really only need to worry about the specific browser/OS you have. If that snippet is kind of working for you, my guess is that in your case, you can kill pinch zoom just by doing that to touchstart and touchmove.

Comment: I'll try killing it on touchstart in the morning. We are running on windows 8.1/Chrome in kiosk mode. We are actually looking to switch to a chrome app instead, they don't have this issue..

Comment: I wanted to update this... As windows has gotten faster the  touches slip through and let the page scale. We've switched from Chrome to a windows store app which has much better scaling/gesture configuration...

Answer (score 1):

There is no current "standard" for disallowing a user from zooming in their web view.  The meta tag for viewport is exactly that.. a meta tag.  The w3 defines meta data as such:

"Metadata content is content that sets up the presentation or behavior of the rest of the content, or that sets up the relationship of the document with other documents, or that conveys other "out of band" information."

And defines a meta tag as follows:

"The meta element represents various kinds of metadata that cannot be expressed using the title, base, link, style, and script elements."

The meta tag is essentially non-normative and the standard doesn't really dictate what it can or can't do as it is up to the browser (or web platform) to dictate what meta information it consumes and, ultimately, ignores.  The viewport meta tag is a webkit meta tag that was created for mobile platforms specifically.

As far as I can tell from research, no such current equivalent tag exists for webkit (or Chrome for that matter) that prevents a user from going to view -> zoom, pressing ctrl (or command) +/-, or doing a pinch gesture on a laptop track pad and zooming accordingly.

Answer (score -7):

easy, use an applet to prevent zoom, java rulez.

Comment: Other than the obvious problem that using a Java applet now requires that the user go through a bunch of "are you sure" and "please enable" dialogs, I doubt that this could actually work. Do you have an example of a Java applet that interferes with the browser's handling of touch input?